# Should I replant same year onion sets?

Tags: onions, onion-sets

In the early Spring, I planted a bunch of [these seeds](http://www.burpee.com/vegetables/onions/onion-granex-yellow-prod001138.html?catId=2030&trail=). I just threw them out there and they grew very close together. I picked them last night after most of the bulbs were exposed

I was just going to go ahead and replant them, [but in the answer to this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/365/onion-seeds-v-onion-sets), it is stated that

> Onion sets are the bulbs from onions that were planted the year before

So should I wait until next Spring to plant them? If so, how should I keep them?

[image: my onions]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to try planting them next spring, [this article describes storing onion sets](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/vegetable/how-to-store-onion-sets-storing-onions-for-planting.htm). I presume that storage of onion sets requires around the same parameters as storing mature onions:

- Don't wash them before storing
- Store at 32-40°F
- Store in a dark place
- Store in a dry place; 65-75% relative humidity
- Make sure there's good ventilation
- Check them occasionally and remove any that are starting to go bad
- Don't store with apples or anything else that gives off ethylene gas

But if you've got enough time for the onions to mature before the end of the growing season, you might be just as well to transplant them and let them get bigger for this year's harvest -- you're more likely to get harvestable onions with less risk of the sets spoiling in storage.