# Will onion sets overwinter in USDA zone 4?

Tags: vegetables, harvesting, overwintering

I have garlic, and ornamental onions and chives planted.  They overwinter, how about those bargain onion sets I bought?  I planted the bag of twenty or thirty but it was a dry summer and those I harvested were not much bigger than when I put them in. They died down in the summer and the ones I left have started new foliage.

I don't know what kind they are but they look like a

> [Yellow Onion, also known as a Brown Onion, is a variety of dry onion
>   with a strong flavor. White inside, its layers of papery skin have a
>   yellow-brown color.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_onion)

If I leave them in the ground will they over winter and grow again next spring?

Comment: what do you mean over winter, you mean you have onions that you didn't harvest this year?

Comment: Any idea what variety they are?  I believe the more onion-y varieties are hardier than the sweeter ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Onion sets are [already in their second year](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/366/51), and onions are biennial, so even if they survived winter, it seems unlikely that they're going to get any better than they already are now.

I had onions grown from seed accidentally survive (I missed a couple at harvest time last fall) through a very mild winter last year in what is normally Z5. I would not expect onions to normally survive a cold winter -- especially with a lot of freeze/thaw cycles.

In your situation, I might harvest most of whatever is there and hope for better luck next year. (I'd probably also leave a few to see what happens -- just for curiosity sake. Deep mulch might help survival. I wouldn't expect much extra growth.)

Comment: and the answer is yes, they will overwinter if they do not set flower their first year